# "have shook hands" or "have shaken hands"?

Tags: grammar, tenses, past-tense

Which one is correct - 'I have shook hands with him.'
 OR
 'I have shaken hands with him.'

Comment: both, the second one makes you sound like a professional handshaker however

Comment: 'I shook' would be acceptable, but 'I have shook' is not correct grammar.

Comment: -1 because the title is different **shook hands** from the question in the body **have shook hands**, and users are writing confusing answers (except for A. Leach) as a result.

Answer (score 4):

[british-english](/questions/tagged/british-english)

This is something a dictionary will tell you, although it may be cryptic:

> **shake**
>   *verb* UK ​ /ʃeɪk/ US ​ /ʃeɪk/ shook, shaken
>
> [[Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/shake)]

The irregular forms are shown after the IPA pronunciations: *shook, shaken.*

*Shook* is the simple past ("I shook his hand"); *shaken* the past participle ("I have shaken it; I had shaken it; I was shaken")

In British English at least, **"I have shook" is not standard.**

Comment: If  I may be so bold to add, neither Americans would say "I have shook hands".

Comment: I guess it's non-standard everywhere. It's more acceptable in some BrE regional variations than others. Although the question shows no research (and is rightly downvoted), how to read the dictionary probably merits an answer, although not on ELU.

Answer (score -1):

[edit] The answer below was based on misreading the question and compares "I shook" with "I have shaken". As Andrew Leach says, "I have shook hands" is incorrect.

Both [I shook and I have shaken] are grammatically correct, but the simple past ("I shook hands with him") is used if you're talking about a particular time, which I imagine you would be. So for example "I shook hands with him last time we met" is correct. The perfect ("I have shaken hands with him") is used in contexts where the time is unspecified, so would suggest that at some point in the past, possibly long ago, you shook hands with him. It sounds a bit odd with that particular verb, but would be the more common tense to use with other verbs, e.g. "I have met him".

Comment: OP asked "I've shook" thought

Comment: @Some_Guy thanks, I misread the question, will edit.

Comment: @Some_Guy but the title has "shook hands". It's the OP's fault, the question should be closed.

Answer (score -2):

Great question: I've always been fascinated with etymology and linguistics in general. As a native English speaker (American English*), also fluent in French, I notice a lot of conventions we* have that go unnoticed.

Though [possibly] gramatically correct, I would think it a lot clumsier to say "have shook" : I don't think in this case that the preceding possessive verb ("to have") is necessary, or really interchangeable the way "have eaten" or "have drank" can be used with or without the "have."

To say you shook someone's hand or have shaken their hand seem to be the only two forms I've ever come across, whether written or in speech, which has another funny layer because we commonly use a form of the having verb (the adverse, "to give") almost interchangeably, in the present and future tenses: if you're going to shake someone's hand or give them a handshake, it seems to operate more like French in the later (although it's also less common in all my years of US English...

You also have to be careful because "shook" and "shaken" have other connotations, not far off from the original meaning. (I'm referring to the slang usage, wherein to evade is to "shake" someone/thing--this has expanded in form over time to different conjugations of the same root--as both verb/adjective; and the other denotation being an adjective for an emotional or physical state.) To be shook up or shaken up have the same meaning. 
I notice that French and English have a lot in common with their compound use of "avoir" and "être" with certain verbs and tenses, but their applications vary by verb.

Enjoyed getting to "nerd out" a little in this explication. Merci d'avances!

Comment: My high school French teacher told me a great and very funny trick she learned in her English study: "eat, ate, eaten. Drink, drank, drunk."

Comment: look up "past simple and present perfect"  Most english speakers don't ever learn the distinction because we don't need to, but there's a reason we say "I ate" and "I've eaten" not "I've ate" and "I eaten"

Comment: The correct answer is "I've shaken".  The reason you've said "I've shook" sounds "clumsy" is because it is grammatically incorrect.

Comment: 1. What's so great about the question in the first place? 2. What *is* the answer: *I have shook* or *I have shaken*? 3. The answer has too much waffling for a very simple grammar question.